# How to generate JWT token on JMETER using a RSA 256 private key Required library or jar file?

Tags: jmeter, jwt, rsa, jmeter-plugins

Currently, I am performing performance testing of API and it is required a dynamic JWT token of **RSA 256 private key**. I didn't find any solution. Can anyone provide me with any JWT jar file and groove code

Comment: Required JWT client library because I am unable to build the JAR, already see the solution in other post

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to go for [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) scripting for this

1. Get a [JWT client library](https://jwt.io/), for instance [this guy](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) will be a good choice and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (make sure to include all the [dependencies](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#maven))
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
4. The example code would be something like:

   ```
   def keyPayr = io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys.keyPairFor(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)

   def now = java.time.Instant.now()

   def clientId = 'foo'

   def jwt = io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder()
           .setAudience('https://example.com')
           .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
           .setExpiration(Date.from(now.plus(5L, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
           .setIssuer(clientId)
           .setSubject(clientId)
           .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
           .signWith(keyPayr.private)
           .compact()

   log.info('Token: ' + jwt)
   ```

Demo:

[image]