# How do I import jwt.io Java library to JMeter

Tags: java, import, jar, jmeter, jwt

I am trying to import the jjwt Java library into JMeter but I get the following error;

> ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223
> Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: io for class:
> Script4

I am attempting to use the jjwt Java library https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt ... which can be found on the https://jwt.io/ website. I've added the files to the JMeter classpath and used a JSR223 sampler to write a script in Groovy... but it doesn't seem to accept it. I'm guessing that this is because it's expecting .jar files but the library is .java files, maybe?

Any theories on how to import this jjwt library would be greatly appreciated.

There is another post here; [How to generate JWT token on JMETER using a RSA 256 private key Required library or jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963935/how-to-generate-jwt-token-on-jmeter-using-a-rsa-256-private-key-required-library/69261501#69261501) that discusses this method and shows that it should work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.java files are "text" files, they need to be [compiled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) into .class files before you can run them in JVM. You can download pre-built .jar from [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt) (make sure to fetch all the [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) as well), or if you prefer the "hard" way:

1. [Install Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
2. Create a file called [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) somewhere with the following content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>org.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>jwt</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <properties>
           <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
       </properties>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
               <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
               <version>0.11.2</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
               <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
               <version>0.11.2</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
               <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
               <version>0.11.2</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
               <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
               <version>1.60</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

   </project>
   ```
3. Open that folder in the terminal application
4. Execute [`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) command
5. Copy everything from `target/dependency` folder to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other location in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
6. Restart JMeter
7. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan and put your [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code using the jjwt library functions there.

Comment: To add a little information for anyone else trying this...

I completed all of the above steps, but JMeter throws the following error:

"org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61"

After a bit of reading it appears that JDK17 doesn't play well here, I downgraded to JDK8 and it all appears to be working now!

Comment: This was super helpful. Worked exactly as in the steps above. Thx.